# Different ways to show Salutations in an email

Tags: vocabulary, email

I was looking for different ways we can greet someone at the start of an email. I usually start my emails with:

> Hi XYZ,
>
> Hope you are doing great!

But if I email a chaplain, a reverend or a priest,  *Hi* seems a bit too informal.

Although in some countries people still use *Dear*, regardless to whom they are mailing, it looks very archaic, unless you are mailing to a family member or a dear one.

For example:

> Dear Dad,
>   Good day!
>
> Dear Mom,
>   How you doing!

I always find myself in a position where *Hi* seems incompletely formal (but less reverent), and *Dear* sounds too much a *love-like* salutation.

I don't have a good collection of English vocabulary, so can anyone suggest what other English words I can use to greet someone in an email (salutations based on whom I am writing the email to)?

Answer (score 1):

Salutations in emails are not absolutely necessary: if colleagues or family members email each other multiple times a day, they are probably going to quickly dispense with any salutation.

But if I am writing an email to someone I do not have an established relationship with, or that I do not write to often, I will almost always start with the tried and true *dear.* This allows the person I am writing to the freedom to reply with the tone he or she prefers. If the relationship between us continues to be formal or impersonal (as in businesslike), I will continue the use of dear.

**Dear** is

1. not at all archaic (see any dictionary of contemporary English), and
2. not a *love-like* salutation in most contexts, including [business communication](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2006/01/greetings_and_s.html), and is
3. *by far the most commonly used salutation in both British and US English, in both formal and informal correspondence* ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salutation)).

English may lack imagination when it comes to salutations; on the other hand, formal communication sticks with tried and true ways. For one thing, it aims to avoid miscommunication. Which is why *dear* is an old standard, still a standard, and likely to remain the standard for some time to come.

At some point, one or both of us may prefer a more informal tone. One can do this by using the person's name (with or without *hello* or *hi,* the latter being the most informal) in the first sentence of an email. After all, a person's name is the sweetest word to his or her ear.

Hello/Hi, Mary, I will send the files to you after I get back from the dentist's.

This approach avoids a separate line for the salutation, which keeps the email tidier.

For specific ways to address *a chaplain, a reverend or a priest,* you can do an internet search for clergy salutation. In most instances, it depends upon the denomination.

In other words, no, English does not have loads of synonyms for *dear*. This might be because written greetings, much like spoken ones, are quasi-ritualistic: *How are you? Fine. And how are you?* There are more differences in spoken greetings, but they often depend on the *social distance* and *power relationship* between the two people speaking, two criteria that will also factor in to how one greets another in a letter or an email.